# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification not calling and only UIKeyboardWillHideNotification calling in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, iphone, notifications, uitextfield, ios9

All is working good till iOS 8.
But when user tap on text field control comes directly in UIKeyboardWillHideNotification notification
Log in console -Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitTruffle-NumberPad; using 675849259_PortraitTruffle_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

Here is the code--

```
`
In view did load
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.txtMobNumber.delegate = self;
    self.txtMobNumber.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:@"UIKeyboardWillShowNotification" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:@"UIKeyboardWillHideNotification" object:nil];
}

notification callback
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Save the height of keyboard and animation duration
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect keyboardRect = [userInfo[@"UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey"] CGRectValue];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"moveKeyboard" context:nil];
    float height = keyboardRect.size.height-60;
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y - height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    //  [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}
// Reset the desired height
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Reset the desired height (keep the duration)
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    CGRect keyboardRect = [userInfo[@"UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey"] CGRectValue];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"moveKeyboard" context:nil];
    float height = keyboardRect.size.height-60;
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,         self.view.frame.origin.y + height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

`
```

Comment: It was problem of simulator

Comment: I have a similar problem. Does your code work only on a real device?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be related to simulator setup, see menu "Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Keyboard Hardware". If this option is ON, you will get `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`, but never `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`.