# KeyboardWillHideNotification not firing in iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9

In iOS 9 our app stopped firing the keyboardwillhide notification. Nothing has changed codewise, was wondering how to get this notification back if possible.

```
// register for keyboard notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
// register for keyboard notifications
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                    object:nil];
```

Comment: Are you running in the simulator? Issue discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32817089/uikeyboardwillshownotification-not-calling-and-only-uikeyboardwillhidenotificati)

Comment: It's happening on device as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322137/uikeyboardwillhide-not-triggered Did you try this answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by the custom keyboard Pinyin which when that particular keyboard was presented was not firing notification properly. It was device specific to devices with the latest version of that keyboard.